# How to re-link git repo to benefit from hard linking

Tags: git

I have several working trees cloned from a remote repo. Had these been cloned from the same local repo I would save a lot of disk space as the clone op would have hard-linked the repo files.

**Is it possible to sort-of re-clone from a different source to generate the hard links?**

I realise I can change the remotes.origin.url but that's not going to delete and re-link the files. Git only manages part of the directory, too, so it's not going to be easy to just delete it and recreate it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If space is a concern, you might even be interested in --shared flag from git clone. What would not even need hardlinks, so it would take even less space. From documentation:

```
When the repository to clone is on the local machine, instead of using hard links, automatically setup .git/objects/info/alternates to share the objects with the source repository. The resulting repository starts out without any object of its own.
```

Why is deleting and recreating and issue - why not do a clone with hardlinks or shared, then copy over the files that are not managed by git `cp -R -n source target`, -n for

```
-n, --no-clobber
do  not  overwrite  an  existing  file  (overrides a previous -i option)
```

Comment: `--shared` isn't quite right for me, but I didn't even think about `cp -n` Thanks!